# Writing characters > 7F (127) as hex strings according to code page 1252 in windows batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, hex

I have a problem with an application creating a batch file. The problem is that my output batch file always is UTF-8 which does not work for batch files. The output contains diacritical marks like é,à,Ä etc. so whatever I do those fail in my batch file.

Thus my question: Is there any way to write any characters above 7F (127 decimal) in my batch file's commands in some 7-bit representation. E.g. as hex strings like "\0xF0" for character 240 or something simmilar.

Of course to use the win 1252 encoding I'd start the batch file with:

```
chcp 1252
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to dbenham, who saw the obvious. [Generate nearly any character, including TAB, from batch](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=3857)

It can be done with `forfiles`.

```
@echo off
call :hex2Char 0x7f char_7F
call :hex2Char 0x80 char_80
echo %char_7F% %char_80%
exit /b

:hex2Char  hexString  rtnVar
  for /f delims^=^ eol^= %%A in (
    'forfiles /p "%~dp0." /m "%~nx0" /c "cmd /c echo(%~1"'
  ) do set "%~2=%%A"
exit /b
```

But even this seems to fail with some characters, like 0xF4 or 0xF5.