# batch: add a unicode header or how to add hex values or any other ways around this?

Tags: batch-file, unicode

I have a batch script that uses drag and drop and creates some html code based on the filenames of the dropped files/folders. 
With

```
chcp 65001
```

I get this to write unicode. All fine and well. In the notepad editor at least, while the browser only shows garbage. When I re-save the file in notepad the file will work all fine in the browser, too. 
Unfortunately it seems the created unicode file is missing two "unicode header" characters (0xFF and 0xFE), right before the file, as comparison with hexdump (http://www.fileformat.info/tool/hexdump.htm) yielded as a result.

On this topic I found this: 
http://www.robvanderwoude.com/type.php#Unicode

The linked file from there sorts of doesn't work (parameter format error) Examples from this site on non-native echos etc. are out of the question. Copying an empty unicodeHeader-Helper File and appending my file works fine, but is very suboptimal, since it would mean, any folder, from which my files are drag and droped would need to have this helper file in. Which is not assumed to be the case as it is unpractical, so that is no good.

Using type is also out of the question, as it creates a whole lot of whitespaces between the characters.

So I was thinking of writing the file with missing header into a temp file, add the two hex values into a file and append the temp file to it. So basically writing the hex chars directly instead of copying them from the empty unicode helper file.

I found this:
http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=3857
and moreover this:
[Writing characters > 7F (127) as hex strings according to code page 1252 in windows batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13150009/writing-characters-7f-127-as-hex-strings-according-to-code-page-1252-in-wind)

I thought I could just replace the example hex values to 0xFF and 0xFE and make it echo to a file:

```
@echo off
call :hex2Char 0xFF char_FF
call :hex2Char 0xFE char_FE
echo %char_FF% %char_800%
exit /b

:hex2Char  hexString  rtnVar
  for /f delims^=^ eol^= %%A in (
    'forfiles /p "%~dp0." /m "%~nx0" /c "cmd /c echo(%~1"'
  ) do set "%~2=%%A" >> temp.txt 
exit /b
```

But it seems it was not to be as simple as that. Two issues that come out of it:
1. It writes some unicode characters in there, but it's not the same as the unicode helper file, as hexdump shows.

```
file name: UniHeader.txt
mime type: 

0000-0003:  ef bb bf                                   


file name: temp.txt
mime type: 

0000-0000:
```

in fact I can change the FF or FE and it still only prints 0000-0000 in the hexdump output...

2. I can add whatever I want after that file (like the code of writing my header-less file and appending it to the created one, the code stops at the second exit /b and does not write anything anymore. (But removing it makes the whole thing not work at all and moving it to the end of the file makes it unable to find the file being dropped onto the bat)
   In all honesty I am not getting through these few codeline at the moment. exit /b marks the end of the command, if I get it correctly, then, why does it continue to work after the first exit /b, but stops at the second exit /b? I also tries with labels and a goto, didn't work.

I am at a loss right now. Is there any elegant way to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Include them inside your batch file.

```
@echo off

    for /f "tokens=2 delims=:" %%f in ('findstr /b /c:"BOFM:" "%~dpnx0"') do echo %%f

exit /b
rem Here starts the special characters part
BOFM:ÿþ:
```

The line which starts with BOFM: is typed as ALT+charchode to get the desired characters.

EDITED -

I give up. I'm not able to make it work consistently with multiple pagecodes across batch file, datafiles and editors. There is no way to guarantee what will be generated. So, i took @foxidrive answer (awesome!) to generate the file prefix and tried.

What i've found is that if we use `FF FE` as a prefix for a file generated from `cmd` not in unicode mode (`/u` parameter) but with a unicode pagecode (65001), we are generating a file marked as unicode (the prefix) but the content is not, we only generate one byte per character. So we get the "chinese"? characters, just a bad translation of a single byte character flow into two byte characters.

If we use the same prefix but from a unicode cmd (with `/u` parameter) and an unicode pagecode (65001), then a real unicode file is generated, and the content is correctly shown from command line, notepad and browsers (tested in ie and firefox). But this is a real unicode file, so two bytes per character are generated.

Instead of `FF FE`, we can send a utf8 BOM `EF BB BF`, from a non unicode cmd but with unicode pagecode. This generates a utf8 with BOM prefix, one or multibyte for character (depends on utf encoding of each character) which shows correctly in editors and browsers but not in command line.

The code (adapted from OP attached files) i've been trying is (to be run from a non unicode cmd):

```
@echo off

    if ["%~1"]==[""] goto :EOF

    setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

    rem File to generate
    set "myFile=aText.txt"

    rem save current pagecode
    for /f "tokens=2 delims=:" %%f in ('chcp') do set "cp=%%f"

    rem Generate BOM
    call :generateBOM "%myFile%"

    rem change to unicode 
    chcp 65001 > nul 

:loop
    echo %1 >> "%myFile%"
    for %%a in ("%1") do (
        echo %%~nxa 
        echo   ^<br^>^<img src='%%~nxa'^>^<br^> 
    ) >> "%myFile%"

    shift
    if ["%~1"]==[""] goto showData
    goto loop   

:showData

    "%myFile%"

:endProcess
    rem Cleanup and restore pagecode
    endlocal & chcp %cp% > nul 

    exit /b 

:generateBOM file
    rem [ EF BB BF ] utf8 bom     encoded value = 77u/
    rem [ FF FE ]    unicode bom  encoded value = //4=
    echo 77u/>"%~1"

    rem Yes, certutil allows decode inplace, so no temporary file needed
    certutil -f -decode "%~1" "%~1" >nul

    endlocal
    goto :EOF
```

Comment: If I understand you right, the characters which are shown as ÿþ: here are suppoed to be the two characters to be added for the unicode header? You mena to directly type them in and insert them into the file? I am not sure, if I got how I am to type the characters after the BOFM: part. At least on my keyboard Alt+FE or ALT-FF is not doing anything. But probably I am getting you totally wrong?

Comment: Keep Alt key pressedn and in the numeric keypad 0255 (0xff) or 0254 (0xFE). In pagecode 850, these characters are shown as you see in answer. The `for` command is just to emphasize and/or separate the codes, but there is no problem to assign them to a variable and echo them. And remember that echo outputs aditional 0x0D 0x0A (crlf). If this is a problem, use the usual `echo %var%|set /p =` trick to remove the crlf

Comment: I got the two characters typed, thanks. However, I am still nut sure, how I get this to work in combination with my own code. As is now, e.g. it loos like this: https://www.dropbox.com/s/jipf45j6vcj82sv/MC%20ND%20Batch%20test.bat but it will stop after the exit \b and do nothing thereafter anymore. I think, I probably still don't understand how to handle the exit \b command properly...

Comment: `exit /b` was added to ensure batch execution does not reach BOFM line. To use the sample code, put the `exit` and `BOFM` lines at the end of batch file, and from your code generate the header using the `for` command, change to your desired pagecode and continue the process execution. Or you could simple set a variable with the desired value and echo it as the header to the output file.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this. In fact, it's even working with a simple echo line right not. But I'd have another question. I noticed, I can write this in notepad with the ALT+Charcode and save this, but when I re-open this with notepad, the line gets a diffrent font and I also can't edit anything in the file anymore (not even comments), without the file not working at all. With notepad++ it works all well, but I am curious, if there is a workaround to that for simple editing?

Comment: Unable to reproduce that behaviour. Notepad works perfectly for me as far as cmd file is not saved as utf8. If saved as utf8 from notepad, as it puts bofm to file, the cmd is editable and runs, but results are wrong. I don't know why you have this problem with notepad.

Comment: It's weird, but I can show you the files: https://mega.co.nz/#!I4omkART!ep-VWR8DytLylzHNDIWcbFhPz7EY46b32z-xkQ0Z-H8 They are both saved in utf8, saving in ANSI is sort of meaningless, as it won't save the special characters.

Comment: The `call :generateBOM "%myFile%"` starts the generation of file, writing the header. In code sample i'm using the utf8 BOM (see explanation of encoded values in rem lines). To output to aText.txt, i echo the encoded (base64) value and ask certutil (from @foxidrive answer) to decode the file in place, without need for a temp file. So we end with the aText.txt file with a utf8 header and ready to accept the rest of the content.

Answer (score 4):

You can embed a base64 encoded section in a batch script which will create a 2 byte file and then use `copy /b "my_header_file.bin" + "myfile.html" newfile.htm"` to add the target file to it.

It uses `certutil` to decode (and certutil with -encode to create the text section) so requires Vista and higher.

Here is the script to create the header file containing hex: FF FE

```
@echo off
(
echo -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
echo //4=
echo -----END CERTIFICATE-----
)>header.tmp
certutil -decode -f header.tmp "my_header_file.bin" >nul
del header.tmp

copy /b "my_header_file.bin" + "myfile.html" "newfile.html"
move /y "newfile.htm" "myfile.html" >nul
del "my_header_file.bin"
```

Comment: I renamed my batch-created html file to "myfile.html" and tried it using your script as is. Weirdly enough, I get a bunch of random Chinese characters and some more unshowable unicodes in the newfile.html. I have Windows 7, so the certutil being unasable shouldn't be the issue. What could it be, that goes wrong?

Comment: I'm guessing that the file is not unicode-with-the-header-missing.  Adding the header would probably make it interpret the file as a double-byte unicode file, so every two adjacent characters make up the one Unicode character.  If you can paste in a hex dump of the start it should be clear, as in a Unicode file many second characters are a hex 00.

Comment: It defnitely is the unicode-with-header missing. I tried opening it and chrome shows garbage for the unicode. Hexdump shows: file name: myfile.html 0000-0010:  44 3a 5c 44-72, after executing the bat with only your code fragment comes out: file name: myfile.html 0000-0010:  44 3a 5c 44-72, so the two characters seem to be added, but the html shows stuff like 㩄䑜潲扰硯䑜睯汮慯獤䑜睯汮慯 [...]. I really haven't got a clue what exactly is going wrong...

Comment: The hex codes you show (both the same) equate to `D:\Dr` which looks like the start of a file path and if so is **not** unicode.

Comment: The full line of the file is D:\Dropbox\Downloads\Downloads\unicodes\中文.png, thus it has unicode. It's also definitely the Unicode-Missing-file, when I simply re-save it with notepad, it works all fine. Through  hexdump gives for this notepad-re-saved file this: 0000-0010:  ef bb bf 44-3a, so perhaps not the right unicodes after all? Can you perhaps tell me, how i could replace ff fe for the ef bb bf...?

Comment: What I was showing is that the hex dump doesn't show double byte characters - and if the characters are single bytes then it's not a unicode file.  Can you post the file to a download site somewhere so we can have a look at the situation?

Comment: Here: https://mega.co.nz/#!JhoWAKRR!VWUYzCt_wP8msXdC0MbfnSWD4f0CU9jdT5U7l-lW4uc I am really clueless, what is for that to show chinese characters in the browser (chrome)

Comment: Firefox warns me: `This website (mega.co.nz) is attempting to store more than 50 MB of data on your computer for offline use.`  Please pick another download site.

Comment: Oh, that's weird. What about this one? https://www.dropbox.com/s/pidycoyo5kpsm34/batchBundle.rar

Comment: Thank you.  The `atext.txt` file is an ansi text file but it has characters from above ascii character 127 and which are displayed as chinese in some code pages.  Maybe they are from unicode names, but the file itself is not unicode. If you use this command `type atext.txt` then in the default codepage they will be displayed differently.  The `newfile.html` does display as chinese characters but it is not a Unicode file so putting a unicode header in it doesn't help anyway.   I'm not experienced in using characters like these, or Unicode - try http://www.dostips.com forum.

Comment: I've taken your answer (i've never tried that! thank you) and adapted to OP linked files. Not sure if everything is ok. All this pagecodes are a nightmare.

Comment: I am a bit confused as to your explanation, but perhaps, could you elaborate in which line and how your are adding the hex FF FE into the file? The echo //4= line? It would appear, FF FE is not working, but it should be hex ef bb bf (upon comparing the hexdumps of the batch created with the notpad-resaved file). Perhaps it may work with that?

Comment: Did you mean to answer @MCND ?

Comment: No actually I mean your explanation and the second half refers to your code snippet

Comment: I didn't add anything to your files once I saw them - it was apparent that they were not unicode.  MC ND had some comments about file formats in his answer.

Comment: Aah, I had totally missed the edit below. Excuse my ignorant question!

Answer (score 2):

You could create the Unicode header (`0xFF 0xFE`) by `CertUtil -decodehex`:

```cmd
rem // Create hexadecimal-encoded file:
> "header.tmp" (echo FF FE)
rem // Decode file to binary header file:
> nul CertUtil -f -decodehex "header.tmp" "header.tmp"

rem // Combine binary header file and Unicode text file:
copy /B "header.tmp" + "U-file.txt" "header.tmp"
rem // Move combined file over original Unicode text file:
move /Y "header.tmp" "U-file.txt"
```

---

A method using `forfiles /P "%~dp0." /M "%~nx0" /C "cmd /C echo(0xFF0xFE"` is problematic, because `echo` produces a trailing line-break. An alternative to `echo(0xFF0xFE` is `< nul set /P ="0xFF0xFE"`, but this does not work either, because `set /P` removes leading white-spaces from the message text, and `0xFF` is considered as such (it is a non-break space), unfortunately.