# console command & output to unicode

Tags: unicode, cmd, windows-console

I know, this is an old question, but none of the answers I found helps in the following scenario:

```
fc /u TextA.txt TextB.txt
```

compares the two Unicode encoded txt files and displays the result correctly (!) on the screen.

As expected,

```
fc /u TextA.txt TextB.txt > Comp.txt
```

does not result in a Unicode encoded file.

Unfortunately the method used in similar situations

```
cmd /u /c fc /u TextA.txt TextB.txt > Comp.txt
```

does not work, the generated file is ANSI encoded.

I hope somebody here can help ...

**EDITED** (after first comments): The problem seems to be that `cmd /u` (or `chcp`) works only with "internal" commands (like `dir`). `fc` is not an internal command ... (Thanks to LotPings!)

Comment: @Fabre: The first example makes no difference, the second seems not to be correct syntax. -- I dont know how to post files here... But you could simply write in Notepad a word and save the file in Unicode, the same for the second file, and then look if the Comp.txt is Unicode or ANSI encoded.

Comment: hey you're right! don't you forget who solves the issues here :) Very very good point. Deserves a little something.

Comment: Well, I'm stuck, just like you. `cmd /u` just doesn't seem to work!

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre `cmd /?` states `/U Causes the output of **internal** commands to a pipe or file to be Unicode` IMO Fc.exe isn't internal. Eventually this helps [how-to-make-unicode-charset-in-cmd-exe-by-default](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14109024) even if the output is UTF8 you could convert to your flavor of UTF

Comment: Seems like a flaw in `fc`. Not sure there's anything you can do about it.

Comment: @LotPings: Thank you very much, a very usefull info! Yes, fc is not an "internal" command, it is stored in "windows\command". Both `cmd /u ...` and e.g. `chcp 65001` work only with internal commands (like dir) and seems to be completely without effect with `fc`. -- Really no way to overcome this???

Comment: `fc` is not an internal command, but redirection like `>` is controlled by `cmd`, so I'd expect `cmd /U` to affect redirections; perhaps you need to change `cmd /u /c fc /u TextA.txt TextB.txt > Comp.txt` to `cmd /u /c fc /u TextA.txt TextB.txt ^> Comp.txt` or to `cmd /u /c "fc /u TextA.txt TextB.txt > Comp.txt"` in order to force the redirection to be handled by the `cmd /U` instance you are invoking rather than the parent instance...

Comment: ...just found out that this does not work either (I can't explain why); anyway, the following works: `cmd /U /C fc /U "TextA.txt" "TextB.txt" ^> "Comp.tmp" ^& type "Comp.tmp" ^> "Comp.txt" & del "Comp.tmp"` (note that the output file does not contain the hex. `FF FE` prefix; see [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19725309) about how to generate it, then you can append to it by changing the portion `^> "Comp.txt"` to `^>^> "Comp.txt"`)

Comment: ...here is a way how to generate such a Unicode header: [batch: add a unicode header or how to add hex values or any other ways around this?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41142676)

Comment: @aschipfl: As already said, `cmd /u` has no effect on the redirection from `fc` (as an external command), so in this redirection already the special characters are not written correctly to the file (which cannot be repaired by converting this file to a unicode encoded file). You can test this by inserting eg the word **koča** (c with caron, easy to copy from a Google search result) in one of the two files: In comp.txt you will see **koca**! -- A strange issue, of course, but I think it is hopeless!

Comment: `powershell -c ". fc.exe /u TextA.txt TextB.txt > Comp.txt"` note **fc.EXE** as `fc` is a powershell alias for `Format-Custom` cmdlet. Also note dot-sourced `. fc.exe`

Comment: @JosefZ: The same as for aschipfl ... this generates a Unicode encoded file, but the special characters are not redirected/written corretly!!!

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer**:

Use PowerShell's [`Compare-Object` cmdlet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.utility/compare-object) as follows:

```
Compare-Object  (Get-Content ".\fileA.txt") (Get-Content ".\fileB.txt")
```

Basically customized output to a file:

```
Compare-Object (Get-Content ".\fileA.txt") (Get-Content ".\fileB.txt") |
  Format-Table -Property SideIndicator, InputObject -AutoSize -HideTableHeaders -Wrap |
    Out-File .\fileAB.txt -Encoding unicode
```

or

```
Compare-Object (Get-Content ".\fileA.txt") (Get-Content ".\fileB.txt") -PassThru |
    Out-File .\fileAB.txt -Encoding unicode
```

**Original answer** (see also *amendment* below):

The `č` letter (*Latin Small Letter C With Caron*, codepoint `U+010D`) appears in code pages `775`/`1257` (*Baltic*) and `852`/`1250` (*Central Europe*). I would suppose the latter as the `koča` word sounds like common Slavonic term for English *hut*, *cabin* or *cottage*.

**Reproduce the problem**. Next example shows possible [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) case between `OEM` and `ANSI` code pages; apparently, `cmd.exe` itself makes some implicit (and *unclear*) character code transformations:

```
D:\test\Unicode> powershell -c "'fileA','fileB'|ForEach-Object {$_; Get-Content .\$_.txt}"
fileA
a lc ěščřžýáíé ď ť ň
a UC ĚŠČŘŽÝÁÍÉ Ď Ť Ň
fileB
b lc ěščřžýáíé ď ť ň
b UC ĚŠČŘŽÝÁÍÉ Ď Ť Ň

D:\test\Unicode> chcp
Active code page: 1250

D:\test\Unicode> fc.exe /U .\fileA.txt .\fileB.txt > .\CompAB_1250.txt

D:\test\Unicode> type .\CompAB_1250.txt
Comparing files .\fileA.txt and .\FILEB.TXT
***** .\fileA.txt
a lc Řçźý§ě ˇ‚ Ô ś ĺ
a UC ·ć¬ü¦íµÖ Ň › Ő
***** .\FILEB.TXT
b lc Řçźý§ě ˇ‚ Ô ś ĺ
b UC ·ć¬ü¦íµÖ Ň › Ő
*****
```

**`cmd` fix:**

```
D:\test\Unicode> chcp 852
Active code page: 852

D:\test\Unicode> fc.exe /U .\fileA.txt .\fileB.txt > .\CompAB_852.txt

D:\test\Unicode> type .\CompAB_852.txt
Comparing files .\fileA.txt and .\FILEB.TXT
***** .\fileA.txt
a lc ěščřžýáíé ď ť ň
a UC ĚŠČŘŽÝÁÍÉ Ď Ť Ň
***** .\FILEB.TXT
b lc ěščřžýáíé ď ť ň
b UC ĚŠČŘŽÝÁÍÉ Ď Ť Ň
*****
```

In above example, both `CompAB_1250.txt` (garbled) and `CompAB_852.txt` (valid) are encoded in a one-byte code page. To get Unicode output, use **PowerShell** as follows:

**PowerShell fix #1**. Force `PowerShell` to use code page `852` from command line (use `chcp 852` command explicitly before calling `powershell`):

```
D:\test\Unicode> chcp 852
Active code page: 852

D:\test\Unicode> powershell -c ". fc.exe /U .\fileA.txt .\fileB.txt > .\CompAB.txt"

D:\test\Unicode> powershell -c "'CompAB' | ForEach-Object {$_; Get-Content .\$_.txt}"
CompAB
Comparing files .\fileA.txt and .\FILEB.TXT
***** .\fileA.txt
a lc ěščřžýáíé ď ť ň
a UC ĚŠČŘŽÝÁÍÉ Ď Ť Ň
***** .\FILEB.TXT
b lc ěščřžýáíé ď ť ň
b UC ĚŠČŘŽÝÁÍÉ Ď Ť Ň
*****
```

**PowerShell fix #2** Force `PowerShell` to use code page `852` *on the fly* regardless of active console code page and keeping the latter unchanged (for illustration, chosen `1252` code page which *does not contain* most of used letters):

```
D:\test\Unicode> chcp 1252
Active code page: 1252

D:\test\Unicode> powershell -c "[System.Console]::OutputEncoding=[System.Text.ASCIIEncoding]::GetEncoding(852);. fc.exe /U .\fileA.txt .\fileB.txt > .\CompAB.txt"

D:\test\Unicode> powershell -c "'CompAB' | ForEach-Object {$_; Get-Content .\$_.txt}"
CompAB
Comparing files .\fileA.txt and .\FILEB.TXT
***** .\fileA.txt
a lc ěščřžýáíé ď ť ň
a UC ĚŠČŘŽÝÁÍÉ Ď Ť Ň
***** .\FILEB.TXT
b lc ěščřžýáíé ď ť ň
b UC ĚŠČŘŽÝÁÍÉ Ď Ť Ň
*****

D:\test\Unicode> chcp
Active code page: 1252
```

Please run next commands *from a newly opened `cmd` window* for further explanation:

```
powershell -c "[console]::OutputEncoding"
chcp 1252
powershell -c "[console]::OutputEncoding"
chcp 1250
powershell -c "[console]::OutputEncoding"
chcp 852
powershell -c "[console]::OutputEncoding"
rem etc. etc. etc.
```

**Edit (amendment)**: finally tested with some Greek characters added to input files; `fc.exe` output looks fine from command line `fc.exe /U .\fileA.txt .\fileB.txt` or even from Powershell:

```
D:\test\Unicode> powershell -c ". fc.exe /U .\fileA.txt .\fileB.txt"
Comparing files .\fileA.txt and .\FILEB.TXT
***** .\fileA.txt
a lc ěščřžýáíé ď ť ň
a    Ελληνικά  ΕΛΛΗΝΙΚΆ
a UC ĚŠČŘŽÝÁÍÉ Ď Ť Ň
***** .\FILEB.TXT
b lc ěščřžýáíé ď ť ň
b    Ελληνικά  ΕΛΛΗΝΙΚΆ
b UC ĚŠČŘŽÝÁÍÉ Ď Ť Ň
*****
```

However, `>` redirecting above output to a file as well as `|` piping it into another cmdlet leads to loss of information so that some characters are either  garbled (via [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake)) or at least replaced by `?` question mark, e.g. as follows:

```
PS D:\test\Unicode> . fc.exe /U .\fileA.txt .\fileB.txt | ForEach-Object {$_}
Comparing files .\fileA.txt and .\FILEB.TXT
***** .\fileA.txt
a lc ěščřžýáíé ď ť ň
a    ????????  ????????
a UC ĚŠČŘŽÝÁÍÉ Ď Ť Ň
***** .\FILEB.TXT
b lc ěščřžýáíé ď ť ň
b    ????????  ????????
b UC ĚŠČŘŽÝÁÍÉ Ď Ť Ň
*****
```

Comment: Wow, wow, wow! Thank you very much for your deep analysis! However, if I understand your method(s) correctly, this is not a "unicode solution"

Comment: Wow, wow, wow! Thank you very much for your deep analysis! However, if I understand your method(s) correctly, this is not a "unicode solution". I used `koča` only as an example. The files in 'real life' could contain characters not only from a `cp 852` but from the entire unicode.

Comment: @newbieforever there's no _"unicode solution"_ in `cmd` as `cmd` is not fully unicode-aware and basically follows [CHAR_INFO structure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682013(v=vs.85).aspx). Answer updated.